# TiledMapTile set texture region gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile, region

I'm having some trouble with setting texture region to my TiledMapTile. It gives me `NullPointerException` and I have no idea why.

Here is some code:

```
TiledMapTile coinTile;

public void show () {
    mapTexture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("maps/other/texture1.png"));

    TextureRegion mapTexture1Region = new TextureRegion(mapTexture1, 32, 0, 16, 16);
    coinTile.setTextureRegion(mapTexture1Region);
}
```

And here is the error:

> 04-09 21:57:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(7792): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 21:57:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(7792):     at com.never.mind.screens.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:225)

which leads to this line:

```
coinTile.setTextureRegion(mapTexture1Region);
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace. Also, where is mapTexture1 defined?

Comment: Updated, as you asked(I'm new to java - I assume that by stacktrace you meant the exact error and line of code?)

Comment: Run up a quick debug log to check that  `Gdx.files.internal("maps/other/texture1.png")` is returning something other than `null`

Comment: I didn't get anything about this texture - only got this:

Thread [<9> GLThread 10] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 <VM does not provide monitor information> 
 GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() line: 1122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a NullPointerException happens when you did not initialize something in your code.

Since you did not provide your full code, I could only give your suggestions.
Like what you did

```
mapTexture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("maps/other/texture1.png"));
```

You should also

```
coinTile = new TiledMapTile () {
@Override
public int getId() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setId(int id) {

}

@Override
public BlendMode getBlendMode() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setBlendMode(BlendMode blendMode) {

}

@Override
public TextureRegion getTextureRegion() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setTextureRegion(TextureRegion textureRegion) {

}

@Override
public float getOffsetX() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setOffsetX(float offsetX) {

}

@Override
public float getOffsetY() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void setOffsetY(float offsetY) {

}

@Override
public MapProperties getProperties() {
    return null;
}

}
```

By the way read the API for spcific paremeters.

Since you are new to java read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to get a grasp of NullPointers

Comment: Thanks. When I added the code you posted, it stopped returning nullpointerexception in coinTile. However, now it gives nullpointerexception when I try to update null Array<Rectangle> with any rectangle :/ I'll mark your answer as solution when I figure out how to fix it and make sure it works :)

Comment: Please open a new question topic as ask that other question. Provide as much information as you can possibly provide in order to obtain best results on stack overflow